# How to change the value of a String in a nested array of Objects?

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have an object called User. The user object contains array of objects. In the nested array of object there is a key called Status. I want to map or change the value of Status from "NEW" to "PROCESSED".

I have tried to iterate through the values of the nested array of objects and replace the corresponding value of Status from "NEW" to "PROCESSED". I tried the following -

```
user.positions().listIterator().forEachRemaining(e->e.positionItems().listIterator().
 forEachRemaining(l->{
  l.fulfillmentStatus().replace("NEW","PROCESSED");
 }));
```

> However, the above code is not able to change the value as **String** is immutable. There is a warning shown with replace that "Result of 'String.replace()' is ignored"

Comment: Do you have a setter for `fulfillmentStatus`?

Comment: @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public record PositionItem(String id,String fulfillmentStatus) {
    }
I have this and I am using lombok.Builder for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace each `PositionItem` with a new one with just the `fulfillmentStatus` changed by using `ListIterator#set` to change the element at each index.

```java
order.positions().forEach(e -> {
    for (var it = e.positionItems().listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        var curr = it.next();
        it.set(curr.toBuilder().fulfillmentStatus(curr.fulfillmentStatus().replace("NEW","PROCESSED")).build());
    }
});
```

As [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488) mentions, [`List#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) can also be used.

```java
order.positions().forEach(e -> 
    e.positionItems().replaceAll(curr ->
        curr.toBuilder().fulfillmentStatus(
            curr.fulfillmentStatus().replace("NEW", "PROCESSED")
        ).build()
    )
);
```